# Como efetuar contagem de itens corretamente?

Tags: php

Como posso fazer para alterar esse código mais abaixo?

Ele pega os valores numéricos postos na MySQL na tabela medias separado por vírgula colocados desta forma na tabela `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`. Então ele conta o total de itens postos nessa tabela separados pela vírgula. Caso ele tenha mais de um valor posto separado por vírgula a mensagem aparece no plural caso contrário aparece no singular. Porém estou tendo um problema: digamos que o valor inserido na MySQL seja assim na tabela `medias`: `1,`. Ele coloca a mensagem no plural e não no singular. Para ficar no singular e necessário que o valor inserido esteja sem a vírgula no lado, desta forma: `1`.

Como posso consertar isso?

```
<?php $contagem = explode(',', $episodios);
$count = count($contagem); ?>
<? if ($count == 1) { ?><div class="separadores"><div class="separador3">Ultimo Episodio Postado</div></div><? }else { ?><div class="separadores"><div class="separador3">Ultimos Episodios Postados</div></div><? } ?>
```

Comment: Se uma resposta resolveu seu problema você pode aceitá-la. Veja o [tour].

Comment: Só estou comentando para reforçar o comentário do @bigown. Sua dúvida hoje (bom não, hoje, hoje) pode ser a de outra pessoa amanhã e ter uma resposta marcada como resolvida auxilia o processo de assimilação desse alguém. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Como você tem vírgula no final da string, o PHP vai contar o `1,` como dois ítens, sendo o primeiro o `1`, e o segundo vazio.

O ideal seria organizar o DB para não ter este tipo de inconsistência, mas para dados já existentes, a função `trim()` vem à calhar, pois ela remove caracteres das pontas das strings, então o resultado vai funcionar bem com ou sem vírgula:

```
<?php
   $episodios = trim( $episodios, ', ' );
   $contagem = explode( ',', $episodios);
   $count = count($contagem);

   if ($count == 1) { ?>
      <div class="separadores"><div class="separador3">Ultimo Episodio Postado</div></div>
<? }else { ?>
      <div class="separadores"><div class="separador3">Ultimos Episodios Postados</div></div>
<? } ?>
```

### Otimizando o código:

Já que o que muda é só o plural, dá pra simplificar de várias maneiras. Eis uma bem legível:

```
<?php
   $episodios = trim( $episodios, ', ' );
   $contagem = explode( ',', $episodios);
   $pl = ( count($contagem) == 1 ) ? '' : 's';

   echo '<div class="separadores"><div class="separador3">';
   echo "Ultimo$pl Episodio$pl Postado$pl";
   echo '</div></div>';
?>
```

Assim, se for singular, `$pl` fica vazio, e se for plural, `$pl` fica com a letra `s`. Dá pra fazer sem usar variáveis, simplesmente mudando o conteúdo do `echo` com a mesma lógica.

Se preferir, use `$count < 2` para que o zero e o um fiquem no singular.

<sup>Discussão sobre o plural do "zero":</sup>
<sub>http://lgcooper.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/zero-e-plural-ou-singular/</sub>
<sub>http://www.ciberduvidas.com/idioma.php?rid=2837</sub>

Comment: Valeu era isso mesmo que eu queria muito obrigada pelo sua ajuda. Eu havia posto a pergunta com erro pois era o inverso.

Answer (score 5):

Se tens a *string* na variavel `$episodios` a terminar com uma `,` isso vai-te gerar uma entrada vazia na matriz.

Uma solução passa pelo uso da função [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) que te permite limpar as entradas vazias na matriz:

```php
$contagem = explode(',', "1,");

if (count(array_filter($contagem)) == 1) {
    echo '
    <div class="separadores">
        <div class="separador3">Ultimo Episodio Postado</div>
    </div>';
}
else {
    echo '
    <div class="separadores">
        <div class="separador3">Ultimos Episodios Postados</div>
    </div>';
}
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/64NXzY).

Comment: **Nota:** Se por algum motivo bizarro a _string_ for `1, `, a solução com `array_filter()` já não se aplica porque o espaço no final da _string_ que vai para a segunda entrada na matriz vai ser considerado como uma entrada válida porque efetivamente tem algo lá dentro (o [whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29)).

Answer (score 3):

Contar quantidades sobre strings não é uma forma muito recomendada.

O ideal é colocar o ID de cada episódio em um Array. Dessa forma você verifica o comprimento do Array. Se o comprimento for maior que um você coloca no plural.

Se $contagem for um vetor, você pode obter seu comprimento com a função [count](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php), assim:

```
count($contagem);
```

Isso também facilita o tratamento do caso no qual não há nenhum episódio (comprimento zero).

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $contagem = explode(',', $episodios);
    $count = count($contagem);
    $mensagem = $count > 2 ? "Ultimos Episodios Postados" : "Ultimo Episodio Postado"; 
    ?>
    <div class="separadores"> <div class="separador3"> <?php echo $mensagem; ?> </div></div>
```

Comment: Obrigada pelo ajuda mais tipo eu sem querer coloquei um erro na explicação no caso acontece o inverso editei a pergunta se poder me ajudar nova mente agradeço.

Comment: Corrigi a resposta,  dessa forma funciona é fácil, mas deve ter soluções melhores

Comment: Se o programa funcionar como descrito, o único problema seria se nao tivesse nada em $episodios

Answer (score 1):

Quero sugerir uma abordagem mais eficiente que resolve com uma única linha (bom, mais de uma por causa da legibilidade aqui no post) o problema usando [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/preg_split):

```
$parts = preg_split(

    '/(\d+),+/', $str, -1,

    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);
```

Com isso, basta contar o array retornado e fazer a condição.

Agora a explicação.

A diferença entre usar [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/preg_split) e usar [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) é que o máximo de controle que [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) te oferece é a quantidade de quebras que ela vai realizar.

Já [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/preg_split) após efetuar a quebra já permite filtrar automaticamente valores vazios através da *bitmask flag* **PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY** combinada como **PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE**

O padrão procurado são números (`\d+`) separados por uma vírgula, mas no array resultantes só queremos os números, então adicinamos um grupo (`(\d+)`) para que a primeira *flag* tenha o que capturar.

Só com isso já temos uma quebra de sucesso, mas com vários índices vazios e é aí que entra a segunda *flag* para ignorá-los.

E tanto faz se existe uma vírgula após o último número da lista ou não e nem se a string está mal formada com mais de uma vírgula entre cada número, a saída vai ser sempre igual.